# Using restful in which application?

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

How can task accomplished with the verb restful in Laravel, What is basic function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [Laravel documentation](http://www.laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) before posting such a basic question.

> Instead of prefixing controller actions with "action_", you may prefix them with the HTTP verb they should respond to.

This means your function 'respond' to the command given - i.e. GET, POST, PUT, DELETE. So a non-restful controller will have:

```
public function action_login()
{
    if ($_POST)
    {
       // Try and login user
    }
    else
    {
       // Show login form
    }
}
```

But a restful controller would be:

```
public function post_login()
{
       // Try and login user
}

public function get_login()
{
       // Show login form
}
```

Comment: What is your 'question' about RESTful? You havent really explained yourself at all..

Comment: Why restful verb we use in Laravel ?

Comment: Look at my modified answer